# Raphael.js Chrome throws a wobbly trying to draw paths using gps coords

Tags: google-chrome, svg, raphael

I've got a problem with drawing paths in Chrome. 
I'm using real gps coordinates, which I want to present on canvas.

Everything seems fine in FF and Safari, yet Chrome doesn't seem to work.

This is a sample code for drawing a path:

```
paths.push(paper.path('M '+lonNW +' '+ latNW+' L '+lonNE +' '+ latNE+' L '+lonSE +' '+ latSE+' L '+lonSW +' '+ latSW+' L '+lonNW +' '+ latNW
            +'M -0.x41558, x1.456541'
            +'L -0.x42379, x1.45619'
            +'M -0.x40759, x1.455802'
            +'L -0.x41569, x1.455448'
        ).attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke:'#FFF'
    }));
```

My apologies for changing some numbers to 'x' but I don't want internet detectives to find out exactly what I'm drawing ;)
The first set of variables - latNW, lonNE etc are the predefined points.

After all the pathes were drawn (there are more, but all of them are created using the technique as above), I'm using this translations in the paper.forEach(..) function:

```
    el.transform("...M 1, 0, 0.45, 1, 0, 0"); 
    el.transform("...R 137.2"); 
    el.transform("...T"+sizeX/2+','+sizeY/2);
    el.scale(-scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
    el.transform('...T' + lonD+ ','+latD);
```

What I get in firefox is this (expected, correct output):[image: FF10 output]

And this is what happens in Chrome 18:
[image]

Any ideas what that might be? I really need it to work in

Comment: any errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: nothing at all, unfortunately.

Comment: could you create a self contained [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this (if only for a sample snippet)?